# TemplateMatching performance in different light conditions

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I was working on hand detection,I tried haar cascade but it doesnt give proper result on most of the images but templateMatching is giving better result.I am just curious if template matching will work in different condition of light and which one is more reliable?

Comment: Asking "which one is better" will yield you opinions. Not a fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The following depends on what your training and input images look like, but you have included no samples:

Of the two options, Haar cascade is most certainly the better choice. OpenCV template matching is not robust against lighting changes, or really any changes at all, period. The template matching more or less looks for an exact image match, not matching features (which the cascade does).